# Is it a G-bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, principal-bundles

Remark 3.3 in Behrend and Dhillon's paper "On the motivic class of the stack of bundles" says $\mu(BP) \mu(G) =\mu(G/P) $ for all parabolic subgroups of G, where this requires the torsor relations only for the group $G$. I wonder how is this proved, do we show that the natural map $G/P\rightarrow */P$ is a $G$-bundle? If yes, could you give me a few hints on how to show it's a $G$-bundle.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: This map is a quotient of the trivial $G$-bundle $G\to  *$, no? (under some functor from $P$-{stacks or whatever} to {stacks or whatever}) Depending on your exact setup I suppose there might be descent conditions to check, but I would expect that those should be straightforward over a point.

Comment: @Tabes Bridges Thanks, let me work on your suggestion. Thanks!